# What kinds of inputs can an LDO take?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

I just recently stumbled across LDOs and understand that they are used to regulate an output voltage. I understand that they require a differential amplifier, a reference voltage, and a pass element of enormous size.

However, I'm unclear as to what inputs can be fed to an LDO. For example, could I feed it a sinusoidal input and expect a dc output? Could I discharge a capacitor through an LDO and see a dc output at the LDO output? Will an LDO be able to take any input and output a dc voltage?

Comment: Could you link to where you've read this about LDOs? This is a weird description of an LDO that I don't really recognize.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-dropout_regulator#History also I'm looking to build one in CMOS so when I mean pass element of enormous size I mean an mosfet of width on the order of 10,000 lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just recently stumbled across LDOs and understand that they are used to regulate an output voltage. I understand that they require a differential amplifier, a reference voltage,

This is essentially true for all linear regulators. An LDO regulator is a linear regulator with lower than usual minimum (Vin-Vout) value.
(Technically an "LDO" does not have to be a **linear** regulator BUT it tends to not make sense to use the term with most switching regulators.

The minimum allowed (Vin-Vout)voltage is called the "dropout voltage".

> ... and a pass element of enormous size.

Pass element size need only be enormous if device rating is enormous.
As with ALL linear regulators the pass element dissipates
Pdis = (Vin - Vout) x Iout + small control power.

> However, I'm unclear as to what inputs can be fed to an LDO.

LDOs are usually monopolar - Vin and Vout are of the same polarity . You COULD make an LDO that output +/-Vreg (+ out when + in, - out when - in) when Vin was of suitably greater magnitude than Vout BUT there would be a "hole" in the middle when Vin is of lower magnitude than |Vout + Vdropout|

> For example, could I feed it a sinusoidal input and expect a dc output?

For almost all applications with Vin is AC a rectifier is used to convert Vin_AC to Vin_DC. USUALLY this is filtered to produce DC of low-enough AC ripple.

If desired you could make Vin = +DC_offset + sine wave such that Vin is always >= Vin-min. Vout_DC will then be constant subject to the AC rejection specification of the LDO. If V_offset_DC + Vsine drops below Vdropout the output will decrease in a usually undefined manner.

> Could I discharge a capacitor through an LDO and see a dc output at the LDO

Presumably into a load.
As long as Vin >= Vout_specified+Vdropout then Vout will be constant. output?

> Will an LDO be able to take any input and output a dc voltage?

As above - Vin must be >= Vout_spec+Vdropout.
Max Vin and Iin or Iout is specified in the data sheet.

Comment: why do you say "presumably into a load" in your answer to my question about the capacitor?

Comment: Also, to be clear, the inputs to an LDO are the power supply voltage and the reference voltage, correct? and furthermore, only the reference voltage determines the regulated output voltage which means that the supply voltage can vary?

Comment: @suhh_drude You said "discharge a capacitor THROUGH an LDO" -> through into what? - an open circuit, a capacitor, a load resistor ...? . I assumed that you meantthat you wishedto power a load at constant voltage from a capacitor

Comment: @suhh_drude An LDO usually does NOT have a separate power supply. It has an input which supplies energy to the load via the LDO. The LDO must extract energy from the input voltage source in order to operate but the main Vin role is energy source for the load. The reference voltage is seldom an "input" in the usual sense. An IC LDO (which is what is usually meant) has an internal reference source - powered by the Vin energy source but at a lower preset reference voltage. The fundamental external connections are ground, Vin relative to ground and Vout relative to ground.

Answer (score 1):

A linear regulator requires a voltage that is some minimum amount above the output voltage, and below some maximum voltage. An AC voltage definitely doesn't match those requirements.

And use your common sense. A circuit without any significant capacitors and/or inductors can only drop voltage as current passes through it (linearly == dissipate the difference).

As always, the datasheet is the finial source of wisdom. Read it!

For an LDO, the datasheet often has some requirement on dynamic impedance of the input and/or output. Read: they require some specific value and type of capacitors.